# Installation requirements of django installing in hostgator dedicated server

Tags: python, django

First, before I install OSQA on my dedicated server at hostgator, I want to know the requirements. I don't want to screw up my server so it's better to ask question first.

I have read a lot of tutorial on the internet regarding Django but I want to clarify something before I proceed.

On my dedicated server I don't use FCGI. Instead I use Mod SuPHP. A lot of tutorial is talking about installing python using FCGI.

My question is if it is safe to install Python if I'm using SuPHP?

Is it safe to use the tutorial on this link: http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/Installing+OSQA+on+CentOS6?focusedCommentId=4784144

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python applications cannot be run via mod_suphp, you'll need to use fcgi or wsgi (or mod_python, but that's really not recommended these days). Other than that, django requires very little: a recent python and the relevant python library for your database of choice.

Comment: i'm glad to see your answer. if i rush on installing Python on my server, then it would be a disaster. btw, can i install wsgi together with su_php? thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely possible.

Comment: i emailed hostgator and they said they can't install it due to prerequisite and may be a compatibility issue even if I pay them. in that case I use another q&a script.